# How to deploy node project to Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, digital-ocean, dokku

I've just created a droplet at **Digital Ocean** with ssh keys. I'm able to connect via ssh from terminal but when I'm trying to push a simple node.js project I get:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>    Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.

I added a repo with this command:

```
git remote add dokku dokku@188.166.110.79:test
sudo git push dokku master
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `sudo`! When you run `sudo git push` git is being run under a different user (root) and uses different ssh keys. Run without `sudo`!

Comment: same thing...it doesn't help

Comment: Then it's not enough information. Please show how do you connect via `ssh`, how do you push and what error do you get. Please show text, not images; copy/paste from terminal to browser.

Comment: I already put it inside my question, these lines are from my terminal...about connection to the droplet: ssh root@188.166.110.79 and after enter paraphrase, that's all

Comment: ➜  MES git:(master) ✗ git push dokku master
dokku@188.166.110.79: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
➜  MES git:(master) ✗

Comment: `ssh root@188.166.110.79` — that's important information, it must be in the original question. The problem is that you connect via `ssh` as `root`, but in git remote you put user `dokku`. Change remote to `root@188.166.110.79:test`. Or fix ssh keys for the user `dokku` and test it with `ssh dokku@188.166.110.79`.

Comment: thank you @phd, but it doesn't help as well...Maybe the problem is in " Please make sure the repository exists" ? Should I create something at server before pushing?

Comment: I was debugging the problem *Permission denied (publickey).* Checking if the repo exists should be the second debugging step. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't create a repo on the droplet...Here is tutorial of Digital Ocean how to set up deployment: [How To Set Up Automatic Deployment with Git with a VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your local ssh-key into dokku instance.
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@SERVER_IP "sudo sshcommand acl-add dokku my-laptop"`